# How to have data align to top of html table row

Tags: html, html-table

I have this html table where I have one cell in the table with `rowSpan = 3`. so in the first column, I have 3 rows with inputs and in the second column I have a picture showing to span all 3 columns.  I am trying to figure out how the browser figured out how to vertically allocate spacing for each of the rows in the first column.

I want then to be "tight" so all the empty space (if the picture is big, goes to the bottom).

But it seems like the empty space is being allocated across each row equally.

Is there anyway to change this behavior . .

Here is the table:

```
<table class="input" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">G:</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <select id="GId" maxlength="50" name="GId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="2">Joe</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="3">Bill</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="imageBorder" rowspan="3" align="center">
            <img class="my_img" src="http://www.example.com/image.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Type:</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <select id="EId" maxlength="50" name="EId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="10"></option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">A</option>
                <option value="4">C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Manager:</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <select id="ManagerPersonId" maxlength="50" name="ManagerPersonId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="204">A</option>
                <option value="183">B</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">PictureL:</td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
            <input id="PictureLink" maxlength="200" name="PictureLink" size="60" value="http://www.example.com/image.png" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is only part of a table.

Comment: Try closing all the `<html>` tags properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to have the first 2 rows at minimum height and if the picture is big, all the space to go on the third line. If this is the case, then put a height to the first 2 lines, something like this:

```
  <table class="input" border="1">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" height="1">G:</td>
       <td valign="top">
            <select id="GId" maxlength="50" name="GId">
                <option value="2">Joe</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="3">Bill</option>
            </select>
       </td>
       <td id="imageBorder" rowspan="3" align="center"><img class="my_img" src="http://www.mysite.com/image.png"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" height="1">Type:</td>
       <td valign="top">
            <select id="EId" maxlength="50" name="EId">
                <option value="10"></option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">A</option>
                <option value="4">C</option>
            </select>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td valign="top">Manager:</td>
        <td valign="top">
            <select id="ManagerPersonId" maxlength="50" name="ManagerPersonId">
                <option value="204">A</option>
                <option value="183">B</option>
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td valign="top">PictureL:</td>
      <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input id="PictureLink" maxlength="200" name="PictureLink" size="60" value="http://www.mysite.com/image.png" type="text">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<tr valign="top">...</tr>
```

also your html looks incomplete.

**UPDATE**

add `style="height:100%;"` on the first 2 rows so the entire extra height is transferred to the 3rd row.

```
<table class="input" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
        <td valign="top">G:</td>
        <td valign="top"><select id="GId" maxlength="50" name="GId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="2">Joe</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="3">Bill</option>
            </select></td>
        <td id="imageBorder" rowspan="3" align="center"><img class="my_img" src="http://www.google.co.in/logos/2010/flintstones10-hp.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
        <td valign="top">Type:</td>
        <td valign="top"><select id="EId" maxlength="50" name="EId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="10"></option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">A</option>
                <option value="4">C</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Manager:</td>
        <td valign="top"><select name="ManagerPersonId" maxlength="50" id="ManagerPersonId">
                <option></option>
                <option value="204">A</option>
                <option value="183">B</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">PictureL:</td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input value="http://www.mysite.com/image.png" size="60" name="PictureLink" maxlength="200" id="PictureLink" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

style the **td** as below to have control on the data alignment.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style = "height:300;width:375;vertical-align:top;"> abc </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height for each row but the last one.

```
<tr style="height: 20px">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 20px">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

This way all the extra space will go to the last row.

Comment: @Kris_R no, it's not actually, it depends on the application.  Anyway if you read the question you'll find that the answer is merely illustrative, and the unit choice is not relevant at all.