# Html table - Not sure how to size certain <td>'s individually

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-table

Curious how to make a TD cell bigger without adjusting the height of the entire row?
I know I can do do inline styling with "rowspan= 7", but that centers the data in the middle of the  cell.

I am trying to build a table like this image and don't know how to size **"Some Data"** and **"Other Data"** cells like so..
[image]

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Heading</td>
    <td>Heading 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8">Some Data</td>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8">Other Data</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS that you have tried and we can help you fix it perhaps.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you're correct that a code should be added. However this will not be necessary as the whole solution to the issue is simple: `vertical-align: top;`. Pretty much basic HTML/CSS that is asked here.

Comment: This should be voted as a duplicate and closed then perhaps rather than answered

Comment: At least one answer here is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830930/125981

Comment: Just a pedantic note: "making a row/column bigger" is not the same as "spanning multiple rows/columns"

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a class to the table cells with rowspan. I used the class: `.rowspan`. Then use css to declare: `vertical-align: top;` and the issue is solved.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}

.rowspan {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Heading</td>
    <td>Heading 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8" class="rowspan">Some Data</td>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>546</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8" class="rowspan">Other Data</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```